# PyQt4 Application takes time on startup for the very fist time

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, tango-controls

I have developed an application using Python 2.7 and PyQt4.
Usually when I start my application it start within a second, but when I do start/restart my computer an than I start application for the very first time, It takes countable amount of time. 
I did following module import to my application.

```
import cStringIO
import imp
import os
import sys
import taurus
import time
import traceback
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from taurus.qt.qtgui.display import TaurusLabel
from taurus.qt.qtgui.util.ui import UILoadable
```

Then I have my main function as

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.debug("In mainWindow - Executing Main function.")
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

I tried using print statement and also checked time for every import.
Sometimes it takes time to import lines

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui
```

and sometime

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

takes too much time to execute.
I don't know why this strange behavior is happening.
My application is working on Ubuntu 16.04 and software version are PyQt4, Python 2.7, Taurus-4.1.1, PyTango 8.1.8,

This behavior happens only for the first time after start up of system. Please suggest something that I can tryout. I think this is some serious issue with the tool or application developed by me.

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Is there any pyqt expert are there? Please suggest something that I can try.. I need to solve this issue for my application.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know this would help, but try to minify the python code using [PyMinifier](https://liftoff.github.io/pyminifier/). 
Minfying and obfuscating helped one of my application.